# Is there a correlation in this scatter plot?

Tags: multiple-regression

Is there a correlation in this scatter plot? I want to confirm whether there is a correlation or not in this scatter plot because I need to use multiple regression.

[image]

Comment: The existence of a pairwise correlation is not relevant to whether or not multiple regression would be useful. Two variables that are uncorrelated on their own may have a strong relationship when other variables are included.

Comment: It is perfectly okay for the two explanatory variables to be uncorrelated as long as they explain much of the variance in the dependent variable. In fact very high correlation is not advantageous because it leads to a multicollinearity problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correlation is a quantity one estimates, rather than saying it is there or isn't.  In this case, the estimate is by most standards very low, as shown by the $R^2$ estimate of 0.006 in the top right corner.  Visually, does it look like there's a strong relationship between the variables? Not to me.

However, this doesn't mean regression isn't the right tool, particularly if there are other explanatory variables available.  "Multiple regression" implies you have more variables, so perhaps some of them will have more explanatory power.  While there's no obvious linear relationship between just these two variables, it looks to me that *something* is going on here. Visually (it might be an illusion) it looks like four or five different clusters of observations.  If that's the case, you'll need the variables that characterise those clusters.

On the other hand, there's plenty of reason for thinking that regression isn't right, too.  For example, you only have about 20 distinct values of MPOSS, and it doesn't look Normally distributed from what can be told from this graph, so at the least you'll need a method that can handle that.

Comment: This went very well until the last paragraph. The marginal distribution of MPOSS and its discreteness don't rule out its being of some use as a predictor. Discreteness can be fine in a predictor (dummy or indicator variables are a case in point) and there is no assumption that a predictor is normally distributed (indicators again make that clear). I guess you know this really....

Comment: I assumed MPOSS was the response, not a predictor variable.

Comment: I see. How much awkward distribution of the response will bite will depend on the data we can't see.